# Sum on a grouped count of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have details of the count of users and the month in the 2nd column and the teams name in the 3rd columns as below. I want the o/p to give the sum of the users column for 7th, 8th and 9th month grouped w.r.t the month.

```
 Count_of_Users Month   Team
 ----------------------------
       1          7       a
       1          8       a
       1          9       a
       1          7       a
       1          8       a
       1          9       a
       1          7       a
       1          8       a
       1          9       a
```

Query:

```
SELECT  
    (COUNT(DISTINCT([username]))) AS A,
    MONTH([Date]) AS B,
    Team
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    [UserName], MONTH([Date]), Team
ORDER BY 
    [UserName], MONTH([Date]), Team
```

This is the query i had for the above o/p. I am not sure if i should be using `UNION ALL` to proceed. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: And? What happened? Why was that the wrong result? You should explain clearly what you want in tabular form and why the current attempt fails to achieve that. And put it in your question, not the comments.

Comment: @underscore_d I want the result as
Count of Users Month Team
3 7 a
3 8 a
3 9 a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but your current version doesn't seem very useful.  Is this what you intend?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [username]) AS A,
       MONTH([Date]) AS B,
       Team
FROM myTable
GROUP BY MONTH([Date]), Team
ORDER BY MONTH([Date]), Team
```

Comment: Ah. Ya. I see my mistake. Thanks!!